# Sql query to segregate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables named as, ticket,branches,payload

ticket

```
ticketid  branchid   waittime    servicetime
   1         3          10           5
   2         4          20           30
```

branches

```
branchid   branchname
   3        Newyork
   4        kansas
```

payload

```
branchid   ticketid   segment
   3          1        GOLD
   4          2        SILVER
```

these are some sample values, now all I want to do is that I want to get branchid from "payload table", branchname from "branches" table, ticketid from "payload" table, segment from "payload" table and waittime and service time from "ticket" table such that:

```
branchid   branchname    ticketid    segment     waittime    servicetime
   3        newyork         1         GOLD         10            5
   4        kansas          2         silver       20            30
```

and I am using mssql and I am new to it.

Answer (score 4):

well you need to join all the tables.

```
SELECT  a.branchid, c.branchname, a.ticketid,
        a.segment, b.waittime,b.servicetime
FROM    payload a
        INNER JOIN ticket b
            ON a.ticketid = b.ticketid
        INNER JOIN branches c
            ON a.branchid = c.branchid
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8395/1)

Comment: Would make a good candidate for a **view** in that database, too!